# redis exception in jedis java code

Tags: redis, jedis

I have this code on java via jedis :

```
int shb1 = jds.storeHypnoBeats(id1, arr1);
```

which calls this function :

```
int storeHypnoBeats(String id,byte[] data)
{
     db.lpush(id.getBytes(),data);
      return 1;

}
```

but when I run the java code I get this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

here is the defintion of arr1 and id :

```
byte[] arr1 = new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
String id1 = "id1";
```

every thing is correct as I have checked, why do I gwt that?!

thanks in advance

Comment: Your key "id" is not a list, you can check key type by using redis "type" function, to sum it up you have already data in this key and it is not a list, so the operation fails.

Comment: actually it works fine!, I had to restart the redis server again. :)

Answer (score 0):

`id.getBytes()` returns an array of byte but signature of `lpush` is:

```
public Long lpush(String key,String... strings)
```

Therefore, key has to be `string` not an `array of byte`.